# Cannot override tranlations (journal-lang)

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I would like to override some Liferay's modules tranlations. I am fallowing: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/overriding-a-modules-language-keys

It works but not for all strings. First of all I would like to override some strings in journal-lang module (com.liferay.journal.lang), but this module doesn't have servlet context name. I have tried to skip that but it doesn't work. How can I override these strings?

I'm also trying to override some core strings (from portal-impl) but some of them remains untranslated. For example "Add Field" (add-field) from defining new form view. Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`journal-lang` is a language components. In order to override some string from them you have to create a component for bundle `com.liferay.journal.web` or `com.liferay.journal.service`.

Answer (score 0):

You've to create a CustomResourceBundle with extends ResourceBundle

```
@Component(immediate = true, property = { "language.id=en_US" }, service = ResourceBundle.class)
public class DefaultCustomResourceBundle extends ResourceBundle {

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
        return _resourceBundle.getKeys();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
        return _resourceBundle.getObject(key);
    }

    private final ResourceBundle _resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("content.Language", UTF8Control.INSTANCE);

}
```

And this should override translations accross the portal.